next-server uses huge memory on Next only debug mode
I am using Next.js version 14.0.1. Recently, the page compilation has become very slow, and I noticed that the memory usage of next-server exceeds 10GB. Each time I navigate to a new route, the memory usage increases by about 1GB. However, the memory usage does not increase for routes that have already been compiled. What could be the problem?

does this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408504/nextjs-13-is-insanely-slow-in-dev-environment solves your problem?

I will try it. Thank your for your answer.
